# Database error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to update my 'settings' table by using Codeigniter's query builder class. 
This is my php code:

```
public function update_settings($post_array) {

    foreach ($post_array as $setting_name => $setting_value) {

        $this->db->set('setting_value', $setting_value);
        $this->db->where('setting_name', $setting_name);
        $query_parts[] = $this->db->get_compiled_update('settings');

    }

    $full_query = implode(';', $query_parts);

    $this->db->query($this->db->escape($full_query));

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1 || $this->db->affected_rows() == 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

When I submit my settings form. bellow error is getting popup.

[image]

Comment: run your queries one by one

Comment: Yeah! but I thought this method is good because, when I run update queries one by one it will make multiple db calls.

Comment: It's ok. Databases are quite accustomed with calls and there is no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks for your input :) but still wanted to know what cause the error. when I copy paste generated sql string in above image into phpmyadmin sql run form, its working fine.

Comment: the error is caused by the fact that you cannot run several queries at once.

Comment: All db updating queries are terminated with semicolon. this should works.

Comment: It's true. MySQL standard policy does not allow execution of multiple queries at once. Possibly some protection against SQL injections.

Comment: Can you print the value of `$query_parts` and tell me whats the output?? I have doubt in extra "\" and "\n" character in your final query passed to `DB_Driver.php`. May be it is due to `$this->db->escape()`.

Comment: Have you tried with `$this->db->update_string()` ([docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html))?

Answer (score 0):

According to the codeignitor docs here is the way to do it.

```
$data = array(
array(
    'title' => 'My title' ,
    'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
    'date' => 'My date 2'
),
array(
    'title' => 'Another title' ,
    'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
    'date' => 'Another date 2'
)
```

);

```
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
// Produces: 
// UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
// ELSE `name` END,
// `date` = CASE 
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
// ELSE `date` END
// WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```